# How to merge two unequal nested list in python?

Tags: python, merge, nested-lists

```
list1 = [['apple','b','c'] ,['dolly','e','f']]
list2 =[['awsme','b','c'] ,['dad','e','f'],['tally','e','f']]


list_combine = [item for sublst in zip(list1, list2) for item in sublst]
print(list_combine)


Expected Output:

list_combine = [['apple','b','c'] ,['dolly','e','f'],['awsme','b','c'] ,['dad','e','f'],['tally','e','f']]
```

How to merge  2 unequal nested list into single nested list in python

Comment: try `print(list1+list2)`

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the '+' operator to join 2 lists.

```
list_combine = list1 + list2
print(list_combine)
```

Output

```
list_combine = [['apple','b','c'] ,['dolly','e','f'],['awsme','b','c'] ,['dad','e','f'],['tally','e','f']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may simply concatenate the two lists by defining a new variable like `list3` or whatever you call.

Also due to [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#whitespace-in-expressions-and-statements), I just modified your code in a more Pythonic way so that it would be more readable. Things like space before comma in not suggested, but after that is recommended. This recommendation is not just in Python, but also it is the better way to write in English grammatically too.

You may check this out and inform me should you have any doubts and questions regarding my answer:

```
list1 = [['apple', 'b', 'c'], ['dolly', 'e', 'f']]
list2 = [['awsme', 'b', 'c'], ['dad', 'e', 'f'], ['tally', 'e', 'f']]
list3 = list1 + list2
print(list3)
```

I hope it would be useful.